# How can I create a temporary table using ANSI SQL?

Tags: database, oracle, ansi-sql

I want to create a temporary table using ANSI SQL so that I could use the same query to create the table in ORACLE as well as MSSQL.

Comment: You can't.  there is no standard for creating a temp table.  That is vendor-specific.

Comment: Temporary tables are included in ANSI SQL (Feature F531), but most products do it in their own ways instead...

Answer (score -3):

```
Create temporary table using the following statement

 CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE my_temp_table (
      id           NUMBER,
      description  VARCHAR2(20)
   )
  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;


   ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS clause indicates that rows should persist beyond the end of the transaction. They will only be removed at the end of the session.
```

Comment: This will work for Oracle only not MSSQL. I wanted to do this in ANSI SQL so that it will not be DB dependent.

Comment: @Ashutosh that is not possible always, each database has its own set of keywords and datatypes. There is no Single syntax for all DBs.

Comment: @Sudipta I understand that. I am working on changing the implementation so that it chooses the query according to the DB used. The problem that I am facing right now is I need to implement "Create table only if exists Else Truncate" in a single query for DB2, MSSQL as well as Oracle. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: No suggestions for a single query. Cannot be done atleast in Oracle, which I know about